# Criar uma tabela no R a partir de um data frame agrupamento os valores por mês

Tags: r

Eu tenho um dataframe df com duas colunas: Numero e Data.

```
df = data.frame(numero = c("10", "20", "30", "40", "50"), data = c("2021-10-01", "2021-10-02", "2021-09-01", "2021-09-01", "2021-08-01"))
```

Preciso criar uma tabela com a quantidade de registros por mês com base nos valores destas colunas. Ficaria assim:

[image: Mes Quantidade Ago 1 Set 2 Out 2]

Comment: Tem dois valores diferentes para oububro. Assim, a tabela desejada não pode ser elaborada. Poderia verificar?

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor? No caso o data frame terá valores diferentes mesmo para cada mês, o que importa no caso, seria quantas vezes o mês se repetiu. A coluna quantidade não é um somatório da coluna Numero, mas uma contagem de vezes que aquele mês se repetiu.

Comment: A sim, entendi.

Comment: Eu usei a função months para obter o mês da coluna Data, mas não consigo evoluir deste ponto. df$mes = months(df$Data, abbreviate = FALSE )

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Com `dplyr` e `lubridate` você pode fazer assim:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(.data = ., across(.cols = data, .fns = ~ ymd(.))) %>% 
  mutate(.data = ., across(.cols = data, .fns = ~ month(., label = TRUE))) %>% 
  group_by(data) %>% 
  summarise(count = n())

#  data  count
#  <ord> <int>
#1 ago       1
#2 set       2
#3 out       2
```

Comment: Note que coloquei os argumentos das funções caso queira explicações sobre como isso funcionou.

Comment: Obrigado, entendi perfeitamente o código.

Answer (score 1):

**Com R base**

```
df$Mes <- format(as.Date(df$data), "%B")  # ou %m para mês como número

table(df$Mes)
#>
#>   agosto  outubro setembro
#>        1        2        2
```

Pode usar `as.data.frame(table(...))` se precisa como data.frame.

**Com *dplyr***

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Mes = format(as.Date(df$data), "%B")) %>%
       group_by(Mes) %>%
       summarise(Quantidade = n())
#>     # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Mes      Quantidade
#>   <chr>         <int>
#> 1 agosto            1
#> 2 outubro           2
#> 3 setembro          2
```

**Com *data.table***

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, Mes := month(data)][, .(Quantidade = .N), Mes]
#>    Mes Quantidade
#> 1:  10          2
#> 2:   9          2
#> 3:   8          1
```

`month` faz parte do data.table. É equivalente à lubridate::month, mas não possui opção de exibir mês como nome.